# Is it possible to add a $ to a field using FileHelpers library

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

Is it possible to add a $ to a field using FileHelpers library?
I have an object

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class TradesToBloombergFileHeaders
{
    [FieldOrder(1)]
    public  Guid id;
    [FieldOrder(2)]
    public  string name;
    [FieldOrder(3)]
    public  double price;
    [FieldOrder(4), FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyyMMdd")]
    public  DateTime date;
}
```

I'm generating a file and want price to be in this format $xxx.xx.
Is it even possible?  I searched, read documentaion and I don't see anything similar to what i need.
Thanks!

Comment: The format string `c2` will do that for you.

Comment: I ended up creating my custom converter: public class MoneyConverter : ConverterBase  
    {  
        private int mDecimals = 3;  
        public override object StringToField(string from)  
        {    
            return Convert.ToDecimal(Decimal.Parse(from) / (10 ^ mDecimals));  
        }

        public override string FieldToString(object fieldValue)
        {
            var val = fieldValue == null ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(fieldValue) ;
            var valString = "$" + val.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return valString;
        }

     }

Answer (score 0):

Probably the attributes:

```
    [FieldOrder(3), FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal, "C")]
    public decimal price;
```

will do that for you. As you see I changed the type to `decimal` which is better for prices/money.

See [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [`ConverterKind` enum](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/FileHelpers.ConverterKind.html).

---

Actually I have never used FileHelpers. The page [Arguments for the Default Converters of the library](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/converter_args.html) seems to indicate that I cannot use a standard format string like `"C"` above. If that is the case, try to imitate the example from [Decimal Custom Converter](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/example_customconv.html) instead, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks. Changed to decimal. I'm getting: You can only use '.' or ',' as decimal or group separators  exception..

Answer (score 0):

What I did once is make the attribute that will get populated by the text file data private, and create a custom public attribute with accessors

```
[FieldOrder(3)]
private double _price;

public string price
{
    get { return string.Format("{0}$", _price.ToString()); }
    set { _price = Convert.ToDouble(value.replace('$', '')); }
}
```

You might want to adjust what the conversion will end up looking like, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

@Francis's answer below did not work for me, and I didn't see the poster's comment with his answer until later. I thought I would clean it up, and called it out as an answer for others who stumble onto this post, trying to figure out how to format the output.

In my case, I was formatting a string data type so I defined the 'StringToField' method instead, but I've provided the code to address the poster's data type below.

```
public class MoneyFormatter : ConverterBase
{
    public override object FieldToString(string fieldValue)
    {
        var val = fieldValue == null ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(fieldValue); 
        return "$" + val.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
    }
}

[FieldOrder(3)]
[FieldConverter(typeof(MoneyFormatter))]
public double price;
```

Answer (score -2):

On output...

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, ${4}", detail.CheckID, detail.IssueDate, detail.StopIndicator, detail.Payee, detail.CheckAmount);
```

Comment: The author wasn't using `Console` or a `TextWriter` to create the CSV file.  They're creating the file using the FileHelpers library.  The question is how to get _FileHelpers_ to write that field as currency.